# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method in correlated query

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper `ProjectTo` to map complex objects to simpler DTO objects:

This works:

```
Dim items = From team In db.Teams.ProjectTo(Of TeamDto)
```

and this works:

```
Dim items = From team In db.Players.ProjectTo(Of TeamDto)
```

But this does not work:

```
Dim items = From team In db.Teams.ProjectTo(Of TeamDto)
    From player In dbPlayers.ProjectTo(Of PlayerDto).
    Where(Function(player) player.TeamId = team.Id).
    OrderByDescending(Function(player) player.TotalPoints).
    Take(5)
```

It causes the dreaded error:

`` LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PlayerDto] ProjectTo[Player](System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[PlayerDto,System.Object]][])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. ``

Something about the correlated query seems to break AutoMapper, but I nothing I've tried works around this.

**UPDATE**: This actually seems to be unrelated to AutoMapper, in that I tried this with a conventional extension method on IQueryable, and this too works when applied to the Teams table, but causes the same problem when applied to the Players table. So this seems to be an EF weirdness.

Comment: "and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." Try searching that in stackoverflow or google.

Comment: I know what the error means generally, but it shouldn't happen in a library specifically designed to create expressions that are translatable into queries, that is, store expressions.